# lambdaj and Multiple Sort Conditions in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, lambdaj

I love [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) and use it a lot, but I can't seem to figure out if it is possible to sort a list using multiple sort conditions.

Here is an example using [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/). Can the same thing be done in lambdaj?

*Sorted first by color then by name:*

```
Function<Fruit, Color> getColorFunction = new Function<Fruit, Color>() {
public Color apply(Fruit from) {
    return from.getColor();
}
};

Function<Fruit, String> getNameFunction = new Function<Fruit, String>() {
public String apply(Fruit from) {
    return from.getName();
}
};

Ordering<Fruit> colorOrdering = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(getColorFunction);
Ordering<Fruit> nameOrdering = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(getNameFunction);

Ordering<Fruit> colorAndNameOrdering = colorOrdering.compound(nameOrdering);

ImmutableSortedSet<Fruit> sortedFruits = ImmutableSortedSet.orderedBy(
    colorAndNameOrdering).addAll(fruits).build();
```

Comment: Isn't [LambdaCollections](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdaCollections) supposed to do that?

Answer (score 12):

Examples of doing that aren't provided on official Lambdaj page, but under hood each time when you are calling `sort` Lambdaj creates comparator for given argument. Below is an example how to sort by multiple attributes.

Sorting:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    final Comparator byName = new ArgumentComparator(on(Fruit.class).getName());
    final Comparator byColor = new ArgumentComparator(on(Fruit.class).getColor());
    final Comparator orderBy = ComparatorUtils.chainedComparator(byName, byColor);

    final List<Fruit> unsorted = Arrays.asList(...);

    final List<Fruit> sorted = sort(unsorted, on(Fruit.class), orderBy);

    System.out.println(sorted);
}
```

Downside:

*There's one non-lambdaj 3rd party method usage. `ComparatorUtils.chainedComparator` - it's from  apache commons collections. If you don't have this as a dependency in your project you can write your own. it just iterates thru all comparators untill non zero returned.*