# Multiple sort conditions with lambdaj

Tags: java, sorting, collections, lambdaj

How can I use multiple sort conditions with lambdaj? e.g. to obtain a List ordered first by name, then by age:

- **Name  Age**
- nameA 14
- nameB 12
- nameB 15
- nameC 10
- nameC 11

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What is nameA 14? Is it a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [lambdaj and Multiple Sort Conditions in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794647/lambdaj-and-multiple-sort-conditions-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into my answer for similar question: [lambdaj and Multiple Sort Conditions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794647/lambdaj-and-multiple-sort-conditions-in-java/10158924#10158924). In short - you need dig little bit into lambdaj source code, but solution is quite straightforward.

Comment: I had already looked that question, but the answer suggests adding another library and not using the nice functional-like lambdaj syntax.  Maybe it is possible with lambdaj-collections?